# Multitasking in a bashscript

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am basically trying to write a bash script that suspends some virtual machines running on a host. However, if I write the script sequentially, VMs will be suspended one at a time. Suspending a VM takes some time to save state. How can I let my script suspend the VMs concurrently. In other words, how can I run commands concurrently in a bash script instead of sequentially?

Answer (score 2):

You can background the tasks.

```
some bash command with options and stuff then with a &
```

Adding the & will send the command to the background and begin the next.

Answer (score 1):

Put a `&` after the command for suspending the the VM.

For example if

```
cmd_to_suspend_vm
```

was your command to run. You would run

```
cmd_to_suspend_vm &
```